# Is the Arca Swiss Z1 compatible with Kirk brackets

Tags: tripod, ball-head

Does anyone know if that Arca Swiss Z1 ball head top plate is compatible with the Kirk angle-bracket?

Comment: The Z1 Fliplock and Classic are adjustable to take any Arca-Swiss style plates.
Rod klukas
US Representative
Arca-Swiss Int.

Answer (score 2):

Kirk [say](http://www.kirkphoto.com/Quick-Release-Lens-Plates.html)

> Our custom machined camera and lens plates are Arca-style compatible

---

P.S. RRS [say](http://reallyrightstuff.com/WebsiteInfo.aspx?fc=78)

> all Really Right Stuff plates and rails will work in all screw-knob
>   versions of Arca-Swiss style clamps.This includes screw-knob versions
>   of Arca-Swiss style clamps from Markins, AcraTech, Arca-Swiss, and
>   Kirk. BUT only Really Right Stuff and Wimberley plates and rails are
>   guaranteed to work with Really Right Stuff lever-release clamps.

P.P.S Sunwayphoto clamps have an [adjustment](http://www.sunwayfoto.com/html/products/201004/182.html) for exactly this reason

[image: Sunwayphoto clamp]

> All SUNWAYFOTO Lever-Release clamps are user-adjustable,  can fit
>   plates from different manufacturers as RRS,Markins, Arca-swiss,
>   Acratech etc.

So it may depend if your z1 has "flip-lock" or not.

---

Update:

The Z1 has an adjustment as shown in this photo (from [the digital picture](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Arca-Swiss-Monoball-Z1-Ballhead-Review.aspx))
[image: Arca-Swiss clamps]